# How can i prevent change on particular div whenever there is a server side call from dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am using dropdownlist in my asp page.
I am using server side method on change as.....

```
<asp:DropDownList id="D1" runat="server" AutoPastBack="true" onSelectedIndexChanged="cbox_server_selectedIndexChanged">
</asp>
<div id="video player"></div>
```

I am also using a div where a video is running and whenever user selecting an item from the list the page is reloaded and the video is stopped.
I want to change only some of the html places and prevent to reload the div where the video is running.
How?

Comment: Do you want to stop page from reloading ?

Comment: so you have to use ajax.

Comment: yes but i want to change some of the treeview elements but it doesn't working for me

Comment: can you please provide me ajax solution ... is there any solution without using ajax?

Comment: Yes you can use updatepanel.

Comment: how? is there any example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax or you can use an update panel.Using update panel will only refresh the part which you want here is Microsoft link about [update panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398867(v=vs.140).aspx).